# GTM Event Click URL value is blank for external URLs/PDF Links

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I have some download/read more buttons on my site, and I'm trying to create a singular event to track clicks on these buttons, while passing the Click URL as an event parameter so I know which button was clicked.

However, the {{Click URL}} parameter is blank every time. Is there a better way to track these? Sometimes the URL is an external URL, and they're also all set to 'target=_blank'. Not sure if that's affecting my event?